# Hash(Dictionary) stored in a List

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nested

I am teaching High School programming in Python and wanted to do a class activity where we make a Pokemon style battle system. (I have one from last year I did in Ruby which works fine). The idea is a random number is generated in a variable and this is used to determine which wild Pokemon attacks the player. I have a list called "wild_pokemon" and I want to store a Hash with key information for each potential wild pokemon the player can battle. So Pikachu and his data would be a Hash stored in index 0, the mr_mime hash in index 1 etc. I like the nested Hash as you can give the data clear names such as "name" or "type".

I am writing a basic test of this in Python and get a error with the nesting of the Hash and can't find any info as to why. The = in the Pikachu Hash is highlighted and it says invalid syntax.

I hope this is clear.

```
import random
import time

wild_pokemon=[pikachu={"Name":"Pikachu", "Type":"Eletric", "Level":random.randint(1,3), "Health":random.randint(15,25),},#List with nested hashes
              mr_mime={"Name":"Mr Mime", "Type":"Lame", "Level":random.randint(1,3), "Health":random.randint(5,10), },
              weedle={"Name":"Weddle", "Type"=>"Bug", "Level":random.randint(1,3), "Health":rand(4,12), }]

def battle():# Placeholdr until i can fix error with the List.
    print("test")


battle()
```

Comment: Python lists dont have keys(is this something that ruby lists have?) - lists only contain values

Comment: If you are going to use index to use the hash, than store namedtuples in a list. Otherwise use nested dicts.

Comment: Hi, thanks for commenting and sorry if my message was confusing. I am fine with the idea of a list having index's. What I am trying to do is store a Hash in a index potion of a list, but get a error when I do. In Ruby it is the same idea (Lists having index's), but I didn't get the error. I think it is something to do with Python not liking the = as part of the stored value (in the index). Thanks

Comment: Hashes == dicts, lists == arrays. Which do you want? You seem to be trying to do both at once. If you want keys, use a dict, `{"pikachu": {"Name": "pikachu" ....}, ...}`. If you want sequential indices, use a list, `[{"Name": "pikachu"}, ...]`

Comment: Use `dict(pikachu={...}, mr_mime={...}, ...)`, but then you will loose the capability to index. Otherwise do: `wild_pokemon = [{...}, {...}, {...}, ...]`, where `wild_pokemon[0]` is `pikachu`.

Comment: I will add an answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answers,  In Ruby you can give each hash a name when storing it in the index position of a list, seems in Python you can't.  Its working now, thanks for your help everyone.
```
import random
import timewild_pokemon=[{"Name":"Pikachu", "Type":"Eletric", "Level":random.randint(1,3), "Health":random.randint(15,25),},#List with nested hashes
              {"Name":"Mr Mime", "Type":"Lame", "Level":random.randint(1,3), "Health":random.randint(5,10), },
              {"Name":"Weddle", "Type":"Bug", "Level":random.randint(1,3), "Health":random.randint(4,12), }]

```

Comment: I have added a way where you could access items both by name and index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python list you don't need to assign the values to keyword. Just store the `dict`s.

```
import random
import time

wild_pokemon=[{"Name":"Pikachu", "Type":"Eletric", "Level":random.randint(1,3), "Health":random.randint(15,25)},#List with nested hashes
              {"Name":"Mr Mime", "Type":"Lame", "Level":random.randint(1,3), "Health":random.randint(5,10)},
              {"Name":"Weddle", "Type":"Bug", "Level":random.randint(1,3), "Health":random.randint(4,12)}]

def battle():
    pos = random.randint(0, 2)
    pokemon = wild_pokemon[pos]
    return pos, pokemon


print(battle())
```

Output:

```
(1, {'Name': 'Mr Mime', 'Type': 'Lame', 'Level': 2, 'Health': 8})
```

You could also go with `random.choice` and use a `nested dict` instead of a list:

```
import random
import time

wild_pokemon=dict(pikachu={"Name":"Pikachu", "Type":"Eletric", "Level":random.randint(1,3), "Health":random.randint(15,25)},#List with nested hashes
              mr_mime={"Name":"Mr Mime", "Type":"Lame", "Level":random.randint(1,3), "Health":random.randint(5,10)},
              weedle={"Name":"Weddle", "Type":"Bug", "Level":random.randint(1,3), "Health":random.randint(4,12)})

def battle():# Placeholdr until i can fix error with the List.
    name = random.choice(list(wild_pokemon.keys()))
    pokemon = wild_pokemon[name]
    return name, pokemon

print(battle())
```

Output:

```
('pikachu', {'Name': 'Pikachu', 'Type': 'Eletric', 'Level': 2, 'Health': 23})
```

You could also use `collections.namedtuple` instead of a `list`, if you want both index and names:

```
import random
import time
from collections import namedtuple
pokemon = namedtuple('pokemon', 'pikachu mr_mime weedle')
wild_pokemon=pokemon(pikachu={"Name":"Pikachu", "Type":"Eletric", "Level":random.randint(1,3), "Health":random.randint(15,25)},#List with nested hashes
              mr_mime={"Name":"Mr Mime", "Type":"Lame", "Level":random.randint(1,3), "Health":random.randint(5,10)},
              weedle={"Name":"Weddle", "Type":"Bug", "Level":random.randint(1,3), "Health":random.randint(4,12)})

def battle():# Placeholdr until i can fix error with the List.
    pos = random.randint(0, 2)
    pokemon = wild_pokemon[pos]
    return pos, pokemon

print(wild_pokemon.pikachu)
print(battle())
```

Output:

```
{'Name': 'Pikachu', 'Type': 'Eletric', 'Level': 1, 'Health': 24}
(0, {'Name': 'Pikachu', 'Type': 'Eletric', 'Level': 1, 'Health': 24})
```